# Divide HTML preview into multiple pages

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Actually, I am trying to create a form live preview. This preview is based on HTML file. I will take inputs from user via HTML FORM and by using jquery I will put the input values to HTML page elements for preview. But I am facing the issue. The issue is listed below:

Issue: After all the content pasted on the HTML PREVIEW PAGE, The page becomes lengthy. I want to slice the HTML into parts and display like the image attached. This image includes the paging also which will make the user travel between different slices of the single HTML preview.

My html page code is attached below, I need to split this html into two parts and hide 2nd part, when we click to view second part then first part will hide and second part will show. I need the design just like the image i have attached earlier.

[Sample Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIsYO.png)

```
<div style="max-width: 1140px; margin:40px auto 40px auto;padding: 0; margin: 0; background: #f2f2f2; font-size: 1rem; line-height: 1.5rem; color: #746873;">
     <header style="border: solid 1px #121212; padding: 1.8rem 0 4.1rem 0;text-align: center; margin-bottom: 3rem;">
        <h1 id="name" style="font-size: 4.6rem;line-height: 1rem;font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: 1px;color: #000; text-transform:uppercase;"><span id="fnameH">Bianca</span> <span id="lnameH">Cruz</span></h1>
        <h2 id="jobtitleH" style="font-size: 2rem;line-height: 0rem; letter-spacing: .29rem; text-transform:uppercase;">Executive managing director</h2>
     </header>
     <section style="display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-ms-flex-wrap:wrap;flex-wrap:wrap;">
        <div style="width: 25%; padding-right: 3rem; position: relative; float: left; box-sizing: border-box;">
           <h3 id="contactH" style="font-size: 2rem; line-height: 2.2rem; text-transform: uppercase; margin:0 0 20px 0; letter-spacing: .20rem;">Contact</h3>
           <div style="display: flex; clear: both; margin-top: 1rem; margin-bottom: 1rem;">
              <div style="font-size: 25px; width: 20%; float: left; margin-top: 3px;">
                 <img id="addresslabelH" src="http://localhost/proresume/public/assets/images/location-icon.png" width="30" alt="location" />
              </div>
              <div style="width: 80%; float: right;">
                 <p id="addressH" style="margin:0">3120 Fairmont Ave. Rushville MO Missouri </p>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div style="display: flex; clear: both; margin-top: 1rem; margin-bottom: 1rem;">
              <div style="font-size: 25px; width: 20%; float: left; margin-top: 3px;">
                 <img id="emaillabelH" src="http://localhost/proresume/public/assets/images/email-icon.png" width="30" alt="email" />
              </div>
              <div style="width: 80%; float: right;">
                 <p style="margin:0"><a id="emailH" style="color:#746873; text-decoration:none;" href="mailto:biancacruz@mail.com">biancacruz@mail.com</a> </p>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div style="display: flex; clear: both; margin-top: 1rem; margin-bottom: 1rem;">
              <div style="font-size: 25px; width: 20%; float: left; margin-top: 3px;">
                 <img id="phoneNumberlabelH" src="http://localhost/proresume/public/assets/images/phone-icon.png" width="30" alt="phone" />
              </div>
              <div style="width: 80%; float: right;">
                 <p id="phoneNumberH" style="margin:0">660-235-9645 </p>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div style="display: flex; clear: both; margin-top: 1rem; margin-bottom: 1rem;">
              <div style="font-size: 25px; width: 20%; float: left; margin-top: 3px;">
                 <img id="sociallabelH1" src="http://localhost/proresume/public/assets/images/url-icon.png" width="30" alt="url" />
              </div>
               
               
                <div style="width: 80%; float: right;" id="socialx">
                  <div id="socialdlH1" class="socialdlH">
                  <a id="sociallinkH1" href="" style="color: #746873; text-decoration:none;">linkedin.com/biancacruz</a>    
                  </div>
                </div>
               
               
              
           </div>
           <div id="eduex">
              <div class="eduDeH">
                 <h3 data-xtr-key="Education" style="font-size: 2rem; line-height: 2.2rem; text-transform: uppercase; margin:40px 0 20px 0; letter-spacing: .20rem;">Education</h3>
                 <p style="color: #000; font-weight:600; margin:15px 0 0 0;">
                    <span id="edustartH1">2010</span> - <span id="eduendH1">2017</span> <span id="degreenameH1">Master of Business</span>
                 </p>
                 <p id="edudescriptionH1" style="margin:5px 0 0 0;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                    consectetuer adipiscing elit,
                    sed diam nonummy nibh
                 </p>
                 <p style="color: #000; font-weight:600; margin:15px 0 0 0;">
                    <span id="edustartH2">2010</span> - <span id="eduendH2">2017</span> <span id="degreenameH2">BA of Commerce</span>
                 </p>
                 <p id="edudescriptionH2" style="margin:5px 0 0 0;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                    consectetuer adipiscing elit,
                    sed diam nonummy nibh
                 </p>
              </div>
           </div>
           <h3 data-xtr-key="Languages" style="font-size: 2rem; line-height: 2.2rem; text-transform: uppercase; margin:40px 0 20px 0; letter-spacing: .20rem; border-bottom: solid 1px #dedede; padding: 0px 0 8px 0;">Languages</h3>
           <p id="languagesnameH1" style="color:#000;font-weight:600; margin:0;">
              Language (native)
           </p>
           <div id="languagesProBarH1" style="background: #b3b3b3; justify-content: flex-start; align-items: center; position: relative; display: flex; height: 15px; width: 100%; margin-top: 4px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
              <span id="languagesProBarValH1" style="box-shadow: 0 10px 40px -10px #8d899b; background: #8d899b; height: 15px; width:100%;"></span>
           </div>
           <p id="languagesnameH2" style="color:#000;font-weight:600; margin:0;">
              Some Language (C1)
           </p>
           <div id="languagesProBarH2" style="background: #b3b3b3; justify-content: flex-start; align-items: center; position: relative; display: flex; height: 15px; width: 100%; margin-top: 4px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
              <span id="languagesProBarValH2" style="box-shadow: 0 10px 40px -10px #8d899b; background: #8d899b; height: 15px; width:80%;"></span>
           </div>
           <p id="languagesnameH3" style="color:#000;font-weight:600; margin:0;">
              One More Language (B1)
           </p>
           <div id="languagesProBarH3" style="background: #b3b3b3; justify-content: flex-start; align-items: center; position: relative; display: flex; height: 15px; width: 100%; margin-top: 4px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
              <span id="languagesProBarValH3" style="box-shadow: 0 10px 40px -10px #8d899b; background: #8d899b; height: 15px; width:60%;"></span>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 75%; position: relative; float: left; box-sizing: border-box; border-left: solid 1px #121212;">
           <div style="position: relative;padding-left: 4rem;padding-bottom: 2.4rem;">
              <span id="timelineLevel01H" style="position: absolute;top: -1px;left: -30px;background: #8d899b;width: 60px; height: 60px;border-radius: 50%; color: #fff;font-size: 30px; font-weight: 600;text-align: center;line-height: 60px;display: block;">01</span>
              <h4 data-xtr-key="Objective" style="margin:0;font-size: 2rem;line-height: 2.4rem; text-transform:uppercase; padding: 0px 0 8px 0;border-bottom: solid 1px #dedede;margin-bottom: 1.3rem;">Professional profile</h4>
              <p id="objectiveH">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh
                 euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad
                 minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
                 ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit
                 esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et
                 accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis
              </p>
           </div>
           <div style="position: relative;padding-left: 4rem;padding-bottom: 2.4rem;">
              <span id="timelineLevel02H" style="position: absolute;top: -1px;left: -30px;background: #8d899b;width: 60px; height: 60px;border-radius: 50%; color: #fff;font-size: 30px; font-weight: 600;text-align: center;line-height: 60px;display: block;">02</span>
              <h4 data-xtr-key="Professional Experience" style="margin:0;font-size: 2rem;line-height: 2.4rem; text-transform:uppercase; padding: 0px 0 8px 0;border-bottom: solid 1px #dedede;margin-bottom: 1.3rem;">Work experience</h4>
              <div id="workex">
                 <div id="workexpH1" class="workexpH">
                    <p style="color: #000; font-weight:600; margin:25px 0 0 0;">
                       <span id="jobstartH1">2010</span> - <span <span id="jobuptoH1">2017</span> 
                       <span id="employernameH1">Company Name</span> / <span id="jobtitleH1">Position</span>
                    </p>
                    <div id="jobdescriptionH1">
                       <p style="margin:5px 0 0 0;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh
                          euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad
                          minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
                          ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit
                       </p>
                       <ul style="margin: 7px 0 0 0;">
                          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>
                          <li>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in</li>
                          <li>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam nisl ut aliquip ex</li>
                          <li>Quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit</li>
                       </ul>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div id="workExLevel02">
                    <p style="color: #000; font-weight:600; margin:25px 0 0 0;">
                       <span id="jobstartH2">2009</span> - <span id="jobuptoH2">2010</span> 
                       <span id="employernameH2">Company Name</span> / <span id="jobtitleH2">Position</span>
                    </p>
                    <div id="jobdescriptionH2">
                       <p style="margin:5px 0 0 0;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh
                          euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
                       </p>
                       <ul  style="margin: 7px 0 0 0;">
                          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>
                          <li>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in</li>
                       </ul>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div id="workExLevel03">
                    <p style="color: #000; font-weight:600; margin:25px 0 0 0;">
                       <span id="jobstartH3">2008</span> - <span id="jobuptoH3">2009</span> 
                       <span id="employernameH3">Company Name</span> / <span id="jobtitleH3">Position</span>
                    </p>
                    <div id="jobdescriptionH3">
                       <p style="margin:5px 0 0 0;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh
                          euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
                       </p>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div style="position: relative;padding-left: 4rem;padding-bottom: 2.4rem;">
              <span id="timelineLevel03H" style="position: absolute;top: -1px;left: -30px;background: #8d899b;width: 60px; height: 60px;border-radius: 50%; color: #fff;font-size: 30px; font-weight: 600;text-align: center;line-height: 60px;display: block;">03</span>
              <h4 data-xtr-key="Skills" style="margin:0;font-size: 2rem;line-height: 2.4rem; text-transform:uppercase; padding: 0px 0 8px 0;border-bottom: solid 1px #dedede;margin-bottom: 1.3rem;">Professional skills</h4>
              <div style="display:block; clear:both">
                 <div style="font-size:20px; margin:5px; position:relative; padding:0; width:5em; height:5em; float:left; border-radius:50%; line-height:5em; background:#8e8a9c; background:-moz-linear-gradient(left,#8e8a9c 0%,#e1deda 100%); background:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,#8e8a9c 0%,#e1deda 100%); background:linear-gradient(to right,#8e8a9c 0%,#e1deda 100%);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#8e8a9c',endColorstr='#e1deda',GradientType=1)">
                    <div style=" text-align: center; display: block; border-radius: 50%; width: 4.3em; height: 4.3em; background-color: #f2f2f2; margin:6px auto 0 auto;">
                       <span id="skillnameH_1" style="padding: 30px 10px 20px 10px; font-size: .8rem; line-height: 1rem; text-transform: uppercase;width: 5em; text-align: center; display: block; color: #010101;  font-weight: 500;">Communi-<br/>cation</span>
                       <div style="border-radius: 50%; width: 5em; height: 5em; position: absolute; clip: rect(0,5em,5em,2.5em);">
                          <div style="border-radius: 50%; width: 5em; height: 5em; position: absolute; clip: rect(0,5em,5em,2.5em);"></div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div id="skilllevelH_2" style="font-size:20px; margin:5px; position:relative; padding:0; width:5em; height:5em; float:left; border-radius:50%; line-height:5em; background:#8e8a9c; background:-moz-linear-gradient(left,#8e8a9c 0%,#e1deda 100%); background:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,#8e8a9c 0%,#e1deda 100%); background:linear-gradient(to right,#8e8a9c 0%,#e1deda 100%);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#8e8a9c',endColorstr='#e1deda',GradientType=1)">
                    <div style=" text-align: center; display: block; border-radius: 50%; width: 4.3em; height: 4.3em; background-color: #f2f2f2; margin:6px auto 0 auto;">
                       <span id="skillnameH_2" style="padding: 30px 10px 20px 10px; font-size: .8rem; line-height: 1rem; text-transform: uppercase;width: 5em; text-align: center; display: block; color: #010101;  font-weight: 500;">Team work</span>
                       <div style="border-radius: 50%; width: 5em; height: 5em; position: absolute; clip: rect(0,5em,5em,2.5em);">
                          <div style="border-radius: 50%; width: 5em; height: 5em; position: absolute; clip: rect(0,5em,5em,2.5em);"></div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div id="skilllevelH_3" style="font-size:20px; margin:5px; position:relative; padding:0; width:5em; height:5em; float:left; border-radius:50%; line-height:5em; background:#8e8a9c; background:-moz-linear-gradient(left,#8e8a9c 0%,#e1deda 100%); background:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,#8e8a9c 0%,#e1deda 100%); background:linear-gradient(to right,#8e8a9c 0%,#e1deda 100%);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#8e8a9c',endColorstr='#e1deda',GradientType=1)">
                    <div style=" text-align: center; display: block; border-radius: 50%; width: 4.3em; height: 4.3em; background-color: #f2f2f2; margin:6px auto 0 auto;">
                       <span id="skillnameH_3" style="padding: 30px 10px 20px 10px; font-size: .8rem; line-height: 1rem; text-transform: uppercase;width: 5em; text-align: center; display: block; color: #010101;  font-weight: 500;">work ethic</span>
                       <div style="border-radius: 50%; width: 5em; height: 5em; position: absolute; clip: rect(0,5em,5em,2.5em);">
                          <div style="border-radius: 50%; width: 5em; height: 5em; position: absolute; clip: rect(0,5em,5em,2.5em);"></div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div id="skilllevelH_4" style="font-size:20px; margin:5px; position:relative; padding:0; width:5em; height:5em; float:left; border-radius:50%; line-height:5em; background:#8e8a9c; background:-moz-linear-gradient(left,#8e8a9c 0%,#e1deda 100%); background:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,#8e8a9c 0%,#e1deda 100%); background:linear-gradient(to right,#8e8a9c 0%,#e1deda 100%);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#8e8a9c',endColorstr='#e1deda',GradientType=1)">
                    <div style="text-align: center; display: block; border-radius: 50%; width: 4.3em; height: 4.3em; background-color: #f2f2f2; margin:6px auto 0 auto;">
                       <span id="skillnameH_4" style="padding: 30px 10px 20px 10px; font-size: .8rem; line-height: 1rem; text-transform: uppercase;width: 5em; text-align: center; display: block; color: #010101;  font-weight: 500;">Problem solving</span>
                       <div style="border-radius: 50%; width: 5em; height: 5em; position: absolute; clip: rect(0,5em,5em,2.5em);">
                          <div style="border-radius: 50%; width: 5em; height: 5em; position: absolute; clip: rect(0,5em,5em,2.5em);"></div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div id="skilllevelH_5" style="font-size:20px; margin:5px; position:relative; padding:0; width:5em; height:5em; float:left; border-radius:50%; line-height:5em; background:#8e8a9c; background:-moz-linear-gradient(left,#8e8a9c 0%,#e1deda 100%); background:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,#8e8a9c 0%,#e1deda 100%); background:linear-gradient(to right,#8e8a9c 0%,#e1deda 100%);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#8e8a9c',endColorstr='#e1deda',GradientType=1)">
                    <div style=" text-align: center; display: block; border-radius: 50%; width: 4.3em; height: 4.3em; background-color: #f2f2f2; margin:6px auto 0 auto;">
                       <span id="skillnameH_5" style="padding: 30px 10px 20px 10px; font-size: .8rem; line-height: 1rem; text-transform: uppercase;width: 5em; text-align: center; display: block; color: #010101;  font-weight: 500;">Time managing</span>
                       <div style="border-radius: 50%; width: 5em; height: 5em; position: absolute; clip: rect(0,5em,5em,2.5em);">
                          <div style="border-radius: 50%; width: 5em; height: 5em; position: absolute; clip: rect(0,5em,5em,2.5em);"></div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div id="skilllevelH_6" style="font-size:20px; margin:5px; position:relative; padding:0; width:5em; height:5em; float:left; border-radius:50%; line-height:5em; background:#8e8a9c; background:-moz-linear-gradient(left,#8e8a9c 0%,#e1deda 100%); background:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,#8e8a9c 0%,#e1deda 100%); background:linear-gradient(to right,#8e8a9c 0%,#e1deda 100%);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#8e8a9c',endColorstr='#e1deda',GradientType=1)">
                    <div style="text-align: center; display: block; border-radius: 50%; width: 4.3em; height: 4.3em; background-color: #f2f2f2; margin:6px auto 0 auto;">
                       <span id="skillnameH_6" style="padding: 36px 10px 20px 10px; font-size: .8rem; line-height: 1rem; text-transform: uppercase;width: 5em; text-align: center; display: block; color: #010101;  font-weight: 500;">flexible</span>
                       <div style="border-radius: 50%; width: 5em; height: 5em; position: absolute; clip: rect(0,5em,5em,2.5em);">
                          <div style="border-radius: 50%; width: 5em; height: 5em; position: absolute; clip: rect(0,5em,5em,2.5em);"></div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </section>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gaurav

you can use the Bootstrap tabs since you did not provide your code snippet, I won't be able to customize this to suit your application but you can edit this and add some JS to make the tabs switch when clicked

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Tabs</h3>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    
  </ul>
  <br>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> This example shows how to create a basic navigation tab. It is not toggleable/dynamic yet (you can't click on the links to display different content)- see the last example in the Bootstrap Tabs and Pills Tutorial to find out how this can be done.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Samperfect for your quick response! Actually I have attached a screenshot image, Please have a look on that Image, I need that type of output, Please have a look on the application 'https://resume.io/app/resumes/8190916/edit', How can I achieve this task?

Comment: In addition to above comment, I have also tried  dom-to-image js library to convert my HTML page into SVG image, Is it possible to convert a single HTML page into multiple SVG images section wise or according to height of the HTML?

Comment: @GauravSaxena i saw the image earlier. I would love to customize the solution to suit your project need but I need the HTML/CSS/JS snippets of the layout (maybe send it though codepen or jsfiddle). 
I tried the link you sent but it required me to sign up.

Comment: Hey! I have just edited my question and paste the html of the file which I need to split.Please have a look!